# Aplicar suma de 0 a n a cada uno de los elementos de un array de n elementos

Tags: php, array, algoritmos

necesito que dado un número entero (pej: $s=2), y un array de n elementos, pej:

```
$arra[0]=1;
$arra[1]=10;
$arra[2]=15;
```

Obtener todos los posibles arrays resultantes en la aplicación de la suma de los valores de $s (0...$s) a cada uno de los elementos del array

Ejemplo:

```
$arra[0]+=1; 
//---
$arra[1]+=1; 
//---
$arra[2]+=1; 
//---
$arra[0]+=2;
//---
$arra[0]+=1;
$arra[1]+=1;
//---
$arra[0]+=1;
$arra[2]+=1;
//---
$arra[1]+=2;
//---
$arra[1]+=1;
$arra[2]+=1;
//---
$arra[2]+=2;
```

Output esperado, el array resultante en cada operación:

```
$arra[0]=2;
    $arra[1]=10;
    $arra[2]=15;

    $arra[0]=1;
    $arra[1]=11;
    $arra[2]=15;

    $arra[0]=1;
    $arra[1]=10;
    $arra[2]=16;

    $arra[0]=3;
    $arra[1]=10;
    $arra[2]=15;

    $arra[0]=2;
    $arra[1]=11;
    $arra[2]=15;

    $arra[0]=2;
    $arra[1]=10;
    $arra[2]=16;

    $arra[0]=1;
    $arra[1]=12;
    $arra[2]=15;

    $arra[0]=1;
    $arra[1]=12;
    $arra[2]=16;

    $arra[0]=1;
    $arra[1]=10;
    $arra[2]=17;
```

Lo que he probado es lo siguiente:

Función test con array de ejemplo y numero $p de ejemplo para testing de resultados:

```
public static function test(){
    $pieces=2;
    $arra[0]=1;
    $arra[1]=10;
    $arra[2]=15;
    $arraResult=self::test2($pieces, $arra);

    dd($arraResult);
}
```

Funcion test2 donde intento replicar lo necesario para a partir de un número $p y un array $arr, tener todos los arrays resultantes:

```
private static function test2($pieces, $arra){
    $arraResult=[];
    for ($p=1; $p<=$pieces; $p++){
        foreach ($arra as $item=>$value){
            $arraResult[$p][$item]=$arra;
            $arraResult[$p][$item][$item]+=$p;
        }
    }
    return $arraResult;
}
```

Resultado obtenido de la llamada sobre el array de ejemplo. Me añade el numero $p a cada uno de los items. Pero siempre entero, es decir, sumo 1 a cada posición, sumo 2 a cada posición... y debería, cuando $p=2, sumar 1 en una posición y 1 en otra, hasta completar todas las posibilidades, como indico en el output esperado.

```
 array:2 [
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [
      0 => 2
      1 => 10
      2 => 15
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 11
      2 => 15
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 10
      2 => 16
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [
      0 => 3
      1 => 10
      2 => 15
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 12
      2 => 15
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 10
      2 => 17
    ]
  ]
]
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Puedes intentar con [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Haz intentado algo?, escribe algun fragmento de codigo que hayas utilizado, asi la comunidad te ayuda mejor, no son bienvenidas las preguntas de "necesito hacer esto", enseña lo que haz intentado

Comment: Claro @sgClaudia98, entiendo, edito el post inicial. Es lógico

Comment: Ok, mucho mejor, que output esperas? los arrays resultantes de que operación? Lo siento, no entiendo la explicación.

Comment: Edito de nuevo el post inicial y añado el autput esperado en el ejemplo dado.
Gracias!

Comment: Vaya, no es trivial. Y, para $s=3, ¿habría que hacer 3, 2+1 y 1+1+1? ¿Qué sucede con $s=4 que es mayor que la longitud del array inicial?